# Cannot subscribe Page to Facebook App

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, api

When I use Facebook Graph API explorer and send POST request to

```
 page_id/subscribed_apps?access_token=access_token
```

All is ok, page appears in the subscribed pages for my webhook.

But when I use FB Node.js API and send request like:

```
  FB.api(
    /${fbSelectedPage}/subscribed_apps,
    'POST',
    {"access_token": ${selectedPageToken}},
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Page does not appear in the subscribed pages for my webhook section. Same is from Postman. It works only from Graph API explorer.

Does someone know the solution?

P.S. Is it real to subscribe many pages to one app and get webhook events from them?

Comment: What does the response say?

Comment: Yes, subscribing multiple pages to the same webhook endpoint is fine. (Your endpoint should be able to handle the traffic, of course.)

Comment: Response say `{success: true}`, and app became subscribed to page feed, it works fine, but it is not subscribed to page messages, nothing come to webhook when page receives message.

Comment: Where did you get the page access token from? Sure it actually belongs to your app? (Debug it, if not sure.)

Comment: I am sure it belongs to my app.  To receive messages and other events sent by Messenger users, the app should enable webhooks integration.
Selected events: feed, messages.

Comment: Webhook receives feed events, but messaging events it receives only when I make POST to `page_id/subscribed_apps?access_token=access_token` from Graph API explorer, and I am administrator of subscribed page.

Comment: Documentation for FB.api has the request method in lower case, try that.

Comment: I tried, it even doesn't work from Postman.

Comment: And you used the same access token in Graph API Explorer? Not one of a different app by any chance (such as the GAE app itself)?

Comment: Yes, all is the same. And it works for feed events. Maybe it works for messages only if I am an administrator or moderator of page? If the post query is being done from postman, page does not appear here in subscribed pages

Comment: [Subscribed Pages](https://pp.userapi.com/c638622/v638622014/5f2da/N2_MrZZaR38.jpg)

Comment: Have you submitted your app for review yet? If not, it might work only for pages where your app admin account is a page admin as well.

Comment: Here are [Approved Items](https://pp.userapi.com/c836438/v836438031/53f16/WCWAqV5ucUw.jpg), is this not enough?

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? I appear to be in the same situation.